# JavaScript Getting Images Ids In Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some images in form and want to get each images ids with javascript ,i have a code but it does not work.

HTML Codes;

```
<form id="form1"> 

<img src="..." id="img1">
<img src="..." id="img2">
<img src="..." id="img3">


</form>
```

JavaScript Codes;

```
 var image=$("form [id='form1']").find('img');

  var i0=image[0].attr('id');
  var i1=image[1].attr('id'); 
  .........
```

How can i get each images id's in form?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `$("form[id='form1']")`, __remove space__ and simple `$("#form1")` will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var arr = [];
$('#form1 img').each(function(i, v){
    arr.push($(this).attr('id'))
})
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: By the way, `$(this).attr('id')` can simply be `this.id`

Comment: Alternatively, `var arr = $('#form1 img').map(function(i, v){
return this.id;
}).get();`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/0xjhvq5r/1/

```
// Start when document is done with loading
$(document).ready(function() {

    // jQuery puts automaticlly all images in an array, if you're selector fits on more html elements
    var $images = $('#form1 img');

    // With this easy loop you select each img in the array and make many magic with this element
    $images.each(function() {
        var $image = $(this),
            imgId = $image.attr('id');
        console.log(imgId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) from the selector that is trying to match the form.

The element with the id "form1" *is* the form, not a descendant of it.

```
form[id='form1']
```

You might want to consider using an id selector instead of an attribute selector too.

```
form#form1
```